# No puedo hacer uso de scrapy.contrib.loader

Tags: python, python-2.7, scraping, scrapy

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
```

Todas estas librerías me van bien, menos la última, la cual me bota un error junto con el método parse_items. Es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/USUARIO/PycharmProjects/scrap/scrap2.py", line 4, in <module> from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader ImportError: No module named contrib.loader –
```

Comment: ¿Y el error sería ...?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USUARIO/PycharmProjects/scrap/scrap2.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
ImportError: No module named contrib.loader

Answer (score 1):

El módulo `contrib` fue eliminado de `scrapy` hace varios años. En la versión 1.6 (actualmente estamos en las 2.2). Por lo que las funciones necesarias, se pueden encontrar en otros módulos, y se pueden hacer de otras formas. En concreto **ItermLoader** lo puedes encontrar aquí:

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
```

También tienes la opción de descargarte la versión 1.6 Pero no te lo recomiendo.